# How to read the from a text file then calculate an average

Tags: c#, filestream

I plan on reading the marks from a text file and then calculating what the average mark is based upon data written in previous code. I haven't been able to read the marks though or calculate how many marks there are as BinaryReader doesn't let you use .Length.
I have tried using an  array to hold each mark but it doesn't like each mark being an integer

```
    public static int CalculateAverage()
    {
        int count = 0;
        int total = 0;
        float average;
        BinaryReader markFile;

        markFile = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("studentMarks.txt", FileMode.Open));
        //A loop to read each line of the file and add it to the total
        {
            //total = total + eachMark;
            //count++;
        }


        //average = total / count;
        //markFile.Close();
        //Console.WriteLine("Average mark:", average);
        return 0;
    }
```

[This is my studentMark.txt file in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kmWa.png)

Comment: Can you show us what the text file looks like, also you don't use a binary reader, there's alternatives

Comment: Yep added! I have only used BinaryWriter/Reader so that's what I have used to enter the data to the file. I know there is stream writer but as I have never used it before I'd rather leave it out

Comment: Why do you use a *Binary*Reader to read a *text* file? Have a look at `StreamReader`.

Comment: Because that's all I've ever used to write to files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `BinerayRead` you can use [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-5.0) for example.

Also with `using` statement is not necessary implement the `close()`.

There is an answer using a while loop, so using `Linq` you can do in one line:

```cs
var avg = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").ToArray().Average(a => Int32.Parse(a));
Console.WriteLine("avg = "+avg); //5
```

Also using `File.ReadAllLines()` according too [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0) the file is loaded into memory and then close, so there is no leak memory problem or whatever.

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array, and then closes the file.

Edit to add the way to read using `BinaryReader`.

First thing to know is you are reading a `txt` file. Unless you have created the file using `BinaryWriter`, the binary reader will not work. And, if you are creating a binary file, there is not a good practice name as `.txt`.

So, assuming your file is binary, you need to loop and read every integer, so this code shoul work.

```cs
var fileName = "file.txt";
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        while (reader.BaseStream.Position < reader.BaseStream.Length)
        {
            total +=reader.ReadInt32();
            count++;
        }

    }
    average = total/count;
    Console.WriteLine("Average = "+average); // 5
}
```

I've used `using` to ensure file is close at the end.

If your file only contains numbers, you only have to use `ReadInt32()` and it will work.

Also, if your file is not binary, obviously, binary writer will not work. By the way, my binary `file.txt` created using `BinaryWriter` looks like this:

[image]

So I'm assuming you dont have a binary file...

Comment: That would be great if I was using StreamReader but I'm using Binary Writer to write to my files in my main code so unfortunately this won't work for my use case.

Comment: No I'm fairly certain I have a binary file as I'm using markFile = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("studentMarks.txt", FileMode.Create)); to create my file

Comment: Ok, if it is created using `BinaryWriter` is allright. Then the second code should works. So hope it helps.

Comment: That code is running fine which is good however for some reason the average is wrong. It is displaying an average of 168637499 which is wrong as the average in my case should be 5 (2 students both with 5 marks each)

Comment: It is because the file is not a binary file. Try to do `Console.WriteLine()` when read the `int32` and you will look that your file has only one line with that value.

Comment: I am separating each mark with a new line as shown in the new picture in the link. Could that be why its reading the marks wrong. They have a 5 on each line but also a symbol in front of it. This is the code used to write to the file:  `studentMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` 
                `markFile.Write(studentMark + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: Instead of ReadInt32() use Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadString().Trim()).

Comment: In your sample file are strings written by BinaryWriter - first symbol in each line is actually length of line

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the average error. ReadInt32 was probably reading the length of the file from  the symbol and adding that to the total